# Using Property to duck type two models

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a django model that can have one of two objects related to it via foreign key (call them `object1` and `object2`). The two other classes are functionally almost identical, but contain slightly different information. At the suggestion of another StackOverflow question, I am using the python method `property()` to set and get whichever object is present. It looks like the following:

```
class Master(models.Model):
    object1=models.ForeignKey(Object1, null=True)
    object2=models.ForeignKey(Object2, null=True)

    def get_object(self):
        if self.object2_id:
            return self.object2
        else:
            return self.object1

    def set_object(self, instance):
        if isinstance(instance, Object2):
            self.object2 = instance
            self.object1 = None
        else:
            self.object2 = None
            self.object1 = instance

    objectInstance = property(get_object, set_object)
```

This is a simplified version of the class. I thought everything was working correctly. I was able to set, and get the information, and could display the data held in `objectInstance` on several of my pages. I'm using django-tables2 to display information in tables, and it too was able to show all the information. However, when I attempt to sort the data (using the convenient arrows that are provided) I get a FieldError:

```
 FieldError at /workflow/list/request/
 Cannot resolve keyword u'objectInstance' into field. Choices are: object1, object2
```

Any idea what's causing this? Or what snippet of code you'd need to see to help determine what the cause is?

EDIT:

So it looks like I'm not the only one with this problem. This post seems to indicate that it's a problem with django-tables2. [Non-queryset data ordering in django-tables2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025565/non-queryset-data-ordering-in-django-tables2)

It seems that while the table can display information held in a `property` it has trouble sorting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer.

The problem was that django-tables2 didn't know how to order non-queryset data. This was solved by explicitly giving the table an order_by argument for each column.

Documentation is here: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#specifying-alternative-ordering-for-a-column

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a decorator, see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684851/2108339).

But the best way is using [Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1)

**EDIT**

Maybe that:

```
class Master(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    objectInstance = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

So, you can do:

```
>>> t = Master(objectInstance=Object2())
>>> t.save()
>>> t.objectInstance
<Object2: a_description>
>>> t.objectInstance = Object1()
>>> t.save()
>>> t.objectInstance
<Object1: a_description>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm a little confused by this. Is it saying I should have another class called `ObjectInstance`, which then has that code inside it, and a foreign key relation to ObjectInstance?

Comment: I found an answer on my own (see below). It ended up just being a problem with django-tables 2 not understanding the data-structure and needing an explicit `order_by` argument be given.